# Beacon not found error message while activating beacon in gimble manager

Tags: android, beacon

can any one knows how to activate beacon? every time beacon not found message comes , i am not able to activate the Gimbal beacon or  i am not understanding flow? how to create a simple android app with Gimbal beacon?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when i was trying to add the beacon to my developer account. In my case the issue was that i was giving the beacons activation code(factory id) incorrect. For example instead of Z2MP-WERTC i was trying with the activation code as Z2MP- WERTC (an extra space). When i corrected that i was able to add the beacons successfully to my account. Please ensure you are giving the correct values  while adding your beacon.

Comment: https://docs.gimbal.com/manuals/index.html this has all the steps for activating the account. Select the manual based on your beacon type.

Comment: I am entering correct activation code still I am getting same error. I have tried multiple times. What can be the issue here ?